# When in time is Samurai Jack?

Tags: samurai-jack

When Aku sends Jack to the future, do we know what year he ends up in? There appears to be a lot of futuristic things that are more advanced then what we currently have, so I assume it's even farther into the future then we are (in comparison to feudal Japan).

[image]

Comment: Can't cite any source, so I won't give a formal answer. But I do remember seeing some articles and memes on the Internet discussing this topic. The focus of the discussion wasn't on the exact year per se, but instead focused on suspicions that this is the futuristic post-apocalyptic world that the Powerpuff Girls used to live in (ie it's the same universe).

Comment: The Powerpuff Girls hypothesis was supported by a Samurai Jack episode where a group of talking dog archaeologists sought their point of origin. The ruined city they were investigating strongly resembled Townsville, The PPGs city. The PPGs had a recurring gag character, who was a talking dog, and was named "Talking Dog".

Comment: My understanding is that it's the present day (or the near future), but in an alternate timeline where certain (mainly Eastern) nations have become dramatically more advanced